# MongoDB + Meteor... how to store users' list of clients data?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

I'm building a web app with Meteor/MongoDB that will have a bunch of users, and each user will manage profile data for a bunch of health clients and store associated profile data for them, like "name", "date of birth", etc.

Currently, I'm storing each user's clients data as embedded documents in the Meteor.users collection, rather than having a separate collection of Users and Clients (and then mapping between them). But I'm not sure this is the right approach.

This app will eventually scale to several thousand users, each with ~50 clients, which is why I thought it would be faster/better to use an embedded document model in MongoDB, rather than having a giant collection of Clients and then mapping them to the associated Users document with client IDs. Let's say 10,000 users each with 50 clients - that would be 500,000 items to traverse through during queries if I used a separate Collection of clients, but only 10,000 items if using the embedded document model with just the Users collection.

But figuring out the publish/subscribe stuff in Meteor, using the "users" database, is proving to be a bit of a pain. It seems like I should be able to just create a collection of Clients, grab all the client records sub-document for user foo, and then stuff them into the Clients collection. But a) I can't figure out how to do that, and b) that doesn't seem like how MongoDB is supposed to work - seems like the "MongoDB style" would be to store Clients in a separate Collection and map them to associated Users with IDs.

There may be a time down the road when Users will have Sub-users that can view their client data, so it starts to seem like the "separate Users and Clients collections" model makes more sense, but 500,000 items in a database sounds like a lot (I have zero database experience).

Any advice here?

Answer (score 2):

There are a several of questions here. I'll try to give succinct answers to as many of them as I see.

> seems like the "MongoDB style" would be to store Clients in a separate Collection and map them to associated Users with IDs.

Generally, mongo favors embedding documents, and meteor favors using smaller, fine-grained data. Based on what you have said, I would put clients in their own collection and not think twice about it. It's clearly the most flexible option.

> Let's say 10,000 users each with 50 clients - that would be 500,000 items to traverse through during queries if I used a separate Collection of clients

That's why databases have [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/). If a common query is going to be "give be all of the clients where a given user is the manager". This could look like:

```
Clients.find({manager: userId});
```

If the `Clients` collection didn't have an index, it would perform a full table scan (look at every document) every time this query was run. However, if you add an index on `manager`, then it would immediately return the necessary ~50 clients. See [this](http://blog.mongohq.com/mongodb-indexing-best-practices/) and [this](http://blog.mongohq.com/explain-explain-understanding-mongo-query-behavior/) for more examples.

> But figuring out the publish/subscribe stuff in Meteor, using the "users" database, is proving to be a bit of a pain.

Here is an example to get the clients that the current user manages:

### client

```
Meteor.subscribe('managedClients');
```

### server

```
Meteor.publish('managedClients', function () {
  return Clients.find({manager: this.userId});
});
```

Comment: Hey @DavidWeldon, thanks for the great reply. I've finally figured out how to do all the proper queries and updates using positional operators and whatnot, but it gets very ugly for several-levels-deep arrays. I'm going to try going with a Clients collection - it should be more flexible down the road, too, if, say, I need to transfer clients from one manager to another.

Question - for ensuring the index, I'm using this on the server:
Meteor.startup(function () {
 Clients._ensureIndex({manager: 1});
}); --> is that correct? Or should I be using the "unique" parameter, too?

Comment: Yes that looks correct. I prefer to add indexes directly to my production mongodb, but you may want it in your code if your dev database is large. Adding a unique `manager` index to `Clients` would make it so no two clients could have the same manager. I suspect this is not what you want. Also, if you found this answer useful, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches will conceptually work with monog, however, given the numbers your talking about, I'd be inclined to set up a schema that linked the clients via userID where needed rather than storing them as sub documents.

Given that you may need to look up the clients in a number of places, putting them under the users data could prove problematic. If on the other hand you will ALWAYS get to the clients via the userID, then the embedded approach has merit.

You may find http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ useful.